# Running Unit Test with Microsoft Moles Host under Visual Studio 2010 Remote Test Agent in TFS Build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, moles, pex

We would like to have our TFS automated CI build and test process use a remote test agent to run our tests separate from our build agent. On normal unit tests that do not use moles or moles host, we have no problems. However, when we include a moles host in our .testsettings or have a moles hosted test (via the HostType("Moles") attribute), the test agent seems to try and get the path to the moled .dlls that the build agent uses. It is almost as if the build agent passes a full path to the test agent and the test agent uses it. We either get a "You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this action" (when in fact each service is running with administrative rights) or a cryptic "MSTest failed returned code 1 expected 0" and no logging information.

My questions for the group:

1. Has anyone gotten MSTest, Moles, TFS Build, and Visual Studio 2010
   Test Controller/Test Agent (not part of the Test Lab setup) to work?
2. If you have gotten it to work, what is your setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work.

While my scenario WAS in TFS Lab Mgmt, I found the problem really didn't relate to lab mgmt, but instead in the fact the the Moles installer looks for registry keys just don't exist when you only install the remote Test Agent without VS 2010 installed.  See the following question for my Question & Answer:

[Microsoft Moles HostType errors in TFS 2010 Lab Management environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210328/microsoft-moles-hosttype-errors-in-tfs-2010-lab-management-environment)

I stress that while I was using TFS Lab Management, it didn't matter.  The issue occurs any time you want to run remote tests with VS installed.

Comment: Yep! This was my experience as well. It seems as if the integration between test agent and build have issues with Moles (as it currently is implemented). I think you _might_ be able to do something like this using PowerShell. Thanks for the response.

Comment: No problem.  Frankly I'm happy that someone else has been getting stuck here because for a while I thought i was going crazy being the only one with this issue.